# using jQuery attr('onclick') returns undefined

Tags: jquery, onclick, undefined, attr

I'm trying to access the 'onclick' attribute of a dynamically generated link:

```
<div class="IDX-linkVirtualTour">
     <p class="detailsLink_p">Virtual Tour</p>
     <div class="IDX-detailsSubLink">
          <a onclick="window.open('http://www.tourfactory.com/736220', 'VirtualTour', 'width=800, height=600, resizable=1, scrollbars=1, status=0, titlebar=0')" href="javascript:void(0)">Virtual Tour</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Element as it appears in firebug ^ 
I can access the href attribute by:

```
var $sublinkA = $('.IDX-detailsSubLink a');
log( 
    $sublinkA[0].href +
    "\n" + 
    $sublinkA[0].onclick); // output the value to firebug console
```

Output to firebug console:
http://www.vdbestates.com/... (intentionally shortened)
undefined

Any ideas?? Thanks!

---

(EDIT) ANSWERED:

```
var $sublinkA = $('.IDX-detailsSubLink a')
```

refers to multiple elements, although not each of these element's  tags have the onclick attribute. I realized, only one of the elements have it. I restructured the jQuery as such:

```
var $virtualLink = $('.IDX-linkVirtualTour .IDX-detailsSubLink > a');
log("onclick: " + $virtualLink.attr('onclick'));
```

and obtained the value of the onclick attribute. 
Moral of the story, be careful trying to access attributes of a set of elements, because they may not all have the desired attribute, hence returning undefined.

Cheers!

Comment: Yep, that's what [my answer indicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550892/using-jquery-attronclick-returns-undefined/6550957#6550957).

Comment: absolutely. I checked ya. Thanks for the help, I just posted my edit before I saw your answer haha. I'll plus 1 you when I am not such a newb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the `href` from the console message is different from that in your HTML, I'd say that the element at index `[0]` is different than the one you're targeting.

If you have multiple instances of `.IDX-detailsSubLink a`, then you're grabbing the first.

If you have only one on the page, then it returns the function that wraps the content of your inline `onclick`.

If you want the actual attribute, you can use `getAttribute()` instead.

```
var $sublinkA = $('.IDX-detailsSubLink a');
log( 
    $sublinkA[0].href +
    "\n" + 
    $sublinkA[0].getAttribute('onclick'));
```

But you still need to be referencing the correct element.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to access the value of the `onclick` attribute, then you can do this:

```
$("elementID").attr("onclick");
```

To fit this in with what you've already got, it would look something like this:

```
var $sublinkA = $('.IDX-detailsSubLink a');
var onclickAttr = $($sublinkA[0]).attr("onclick");
```

Comment: that is what he said isn't working: $("elementID").attr("onclick");

Comment: @david - his code is this: `$sublinkA[0].onclick`, there is no use of the `attr` function.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen for the help; sorry about the ambiguity - I suppose the title indicated that I had -tried- the .attr() method to no avail. I posted my solution below. Thanks!!

Comment: If there's no `.onclick` property, then there must not be an `onclick` attribute either. So `.attr()` wouldn't give any better result.